# Rails join table and multi sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I want to do is to join table and sum 3 columns.

```
   self.document_products.joins("JOIN products ON products.id = document_products.product_id").group("products.tax_id").select("sum(a), sum(b), sum(c)")
```

Gives me

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<DocumentProduct id: nil>]>
```

Something like that works:

```
   self.document_products.joins("JOIN products ON products.id = document_products.product_id").group("products.tax_id").sum("a")
```

But I want to have 3 sums. I can`t do sum("a, b, c"). Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

So, the code is building a SQL query using the ActiveRecord chained method syntax. It's possible to use `.to_sql` as the final part of most such chains (basically, as long as it's still an ActiveRecord object, rather than having been converted to an Array, for example) to see the SQL generated, or indeed inspecting the log, if it's on. Considering the common part of the chain:

```
self.document_products.joins("JOIN products ON products.id = document_products.product_id").group("products.tax_id")
```

This generates something like (might not be exact, because I'm guessing a little about your application):

```
SELECT "document_products".* FROM "document_products" JOIN products ON products.id = document_products.product_id WHERE "document_products"."document_id" = 1497 GROUP BY products.tax_id
```

The two final methods you list are very different; `select` selects which columns in the query to return, whereas `sum` is an aggregate function which expects a single value to be returned in each case. Considering the `select`, we get something like the following generated:

```
SELECT SUM(products.a), SUM(products.b), SUM(products.c) FROM "document_products" JOIN products ON products.id = document_products.product_id WHERE "document_products"."document_id" = 1497 GROUP BY products.tax_id
```

When this query is interpreted, the expected data cannot be found, leading to the problem described. Ensuring that the `GROUP BY` clause is included in the `SELECT` part, however, yields the necessary information. Try something like this:

```
self.document_products.joins("JOIN products ON products.id = document_products.product_id").group("products.tax_id").select("products.tax_id, sum(a), sum(b), sum(c)")
```

This generates SQL something like:

```
SELECT products.tax_id, SUM(products.a), SUM(products.b), SUM(products.c) FROM "document_products" JOIN products ON products.id = document_products.product_id WHERE "document_products"."document_id" = 1497 GROUP BY products.tax_id
```

This appears to return the necessary information, and is, I think, what you're looking for (or close to it).

Comment: Thanks, the answer is to name sums in select: ...select("sum(a) as a, sum(b) as b, sum(c) as c")